# How do I check if a input is an integer type

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I tried to make a odd/even 'calculator' in python and it keeps popping up errors. Here's the code:

```
def odd_even():
    print("Welcome to Odd/Even")
    num = input("Pick a number: ")
    num2 = num/2
    if num2 == int:
        print("This number is even")
    else:
        print("This number is odd")
```

Id like to know whats causing the errors and solutions to them

Comment: What errors are you getting? Make sure you're consistent in your use of spaces versus tabs when indenting.

Comment: What do you expect `num2 == int` to do? If you want to know if a number is even, it's when `num % 2 == 0`

Comment: `input` returns a string, so `num` is a string. You can't divide a string by 2. You probably wanted `num = int(input(…))`.

Comment: Meanwhile, even if by `num2 == int` you meant `isinstance(num2, int)`, that won't do anything useful. Try it in your interactive interpreter: `4 / 2` is not the int 2, it's the float 2.0. What you probably want to do is check for the _remainder_: `if num % 2 == 0:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the line:    `num = input("Pick a number: ")`
Because input method always returns a `String`,so you should convert it into int to performs the `integer` operation
The currect code is:

```
num =int( input("Pick a number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do math with strings convert it to int

```
try:
    num = int(input("Pick a number: "))
except ValueError:
    print('This is not a number!')
    return
```